# Resaults of conditional statments

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

Is there a way to represent multiple conditional statements in a truth table and find the results of them: e.g.,

- if person $A$ passes the exam, then person $B$ re-enters the exam.
- if person $A$ re-enters the exam, then person $B$ fails the exam.
- if person $B$ fails the exam, then person $C$ re-enters the exam.
- if person $C$ passes the exam, then person $A$ re-enters the exam.
- according to those who is going to pass, re-enter, fail the exam.

Now what I have done so far, is that I've created a truth table for each statement assuming it's true using the **IF.. THEN** statement. But, I can't workout a method to connect such statements with each other to find the underlying logic.

Comment: what does "reenter the exam" mean  and is it mutually exclusive or compatible with passing or failing the exam?

Comment: i can't find out too , i came over that question when i was studying and i couldn't solve it , i still don't know how to represent a mid-situation like this
@fleablood

Comment: Assuming the three are mutually exclusive: Case 1: A passes; B reenters;C can not pass but can reenter or fail.  Case 2:If A renters B fails an C reenters.  Case 3: A fails;  C can't pass B can do anything but if B fails C renters so 8 possibilities are AP, BR, CR:: AP BR,CF:: AR,BF,CR::AF,BP,CR::AF,BP,CF::AF,BR,CR::AF,BR,CF or AF,BF,CR  In any event C can not pass.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that three people are sitting for an exam with three results: pass, fail, or re-enter.

$A{=}P\to B{=}R,\\ A{=}R \to B{=}F,\\ B{=}F \to C{=}R,\\ C{=}P\to A{=}R$

From this all I can see is the chain, $C{=}P~\to A{=}R,~\to B{=}F,~\to C{=}R$ means $C{\neq}P$.

Breaking into mutually exclusive cases:

$$\Big(A{=}P\wedge B{=}R\wedge\big(C{=}F\vee C{=}R\big)\Big)\vee\\\Big(A{=}F\wedge\big(((B{=}P\vee B{=}R)\wedge(C{=}F\vee C{=}R))\vee(B{=}F\wedge C{=}R)\big)\Big)\vee\\\Big(A{=}R\wedge B{=}F\wedge C{=}R\Big)$$

---

Complete the Truth Tableau:

$\boxed{\begin{array}{ccc:cccc|c} A & B & C & A{=}P\to B{=}R & A{=}R \to B{=}F & B{=}F \to C{=}R & C{=}P\to A{=}R \\ \hline
P & P & P & \bot & \top & \top & \bot & \\
P & P & F & \bot & \top & \top & \top & \\
P & P & R & \bot & \top & \top & \top & \\
P & F & P & \bot & \top & \bot & \bot & \\
P & F & F & \bot & \top & \bot & \top & \\
P & F & R & \bot & \top & \top & \top & \\
P & R & P & \top & \top & \top & \bot & \\
P & R & F & \top & \top & \top & \top & \checkmark \\
P & R & R & \top & \top & \top & \top & \checkmark \\
F & P & P & & & & & \\
F & P & F & & & & & \\
F & P & R & & & & & \\
F & F & P & & & & & \\
F & F & F & & & & & \\
F & F & R & & & & & \\
F & R & P & & & & & \\
F & R & F & & & & & \\
F & R & R & & & & & \\
R & P & P & & & & & \\
R & P & F & & & & & \\
R & P & R & & & & & \\
R & F & P & & & & & \\
R & F & F & & & & & \\
R & F & R & & & & & \\
R & R & P & & & & & \\
R & R & F & & & & & \\
R & R & R & & & & & \\
\end{array}}$

Comment: can you explain what you've done here , 
moreover , how do we turn those into truth table ?

Comment: @Moutasem The truth tableau is completed by evaluating the four implications for each of the 27 possible states of A,B,C.  When all four implications hold true, then the states on that row are plausible.